# Android: setPictureFormat() error

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner in Andoird, currently trying to write an application using the Camera class of Android in Eclipse. The problem is when I call the parameters.setPictureFormat() method with ImageFormat.JPEG as the argument, I get an error.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h){
   Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();

   parameters.setPreviewSize(854,480);  // (h,w)
   parameters.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
   parameters.set("jpeg-quality", 100);
   parameters.set("orientation", "lanscape");
   parameters.set("rotation", 90);
   mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
   mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

And I get this error in return:

```
ImageFormat cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I've tried using PixelFormat.JPEG as well, but I get the same error that says "PixelFormat cannot be resolved to a variable". I've checked, it's not importing android.R. I also tried importing android.graphics.ImageFormat but it doesn't work.

Could anybody help point out what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what target are you trying to build this app? android.graphics.ImageFormat is only available for android 2.2. I suppose your selected target is android 2.0 or below.

Two important points:

- For Android 1.5 and Android 1.6, you
  can't call setPictureFormat. Only
  getPictureFormat is supported.
- For Android 2.0 you will need to call
  getSupportedPictureFormat to get the
  list of formats supported.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'm am running this application on Motorola Milestone, which is on Android 2.1. I did suspect it might be because the target API level does not support ImageFormat but I could not find any other documentation for Android 2.1 and below. So does this mean I need to call getSupportedPictureFormat as well?

Comment: No, you don't have to. You can use SetPictureFormat(PixelFormat.JPEG) to do the same you want to do for android 2.2.